# xargs string with docker -e creates one major environment variable

Tags: bash, docker, xargs

I'm trying to construct some docker command from an arbitrary environment json array, so I did some parsing with jq and then tried to pass it to xargs.  However that seems to be getting parsed as one single flag?

```bash
echo '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}' | jq -r '. | to_entries | map([.key,.value] | join("=")) | join(" -e ")' | xargs -I '{}' docker run -e {} busybox:latest env
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=830b80ada4a8
a=b -e c=d
HOME=/root
```

Yet when I print out xargs with `-t` it works fine for me?

```
echo '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}' | jq -r '. | to_entries | map([.key,.value] | join("=")) | join(" -e ")' | xargs -t -I '{}' docker run -e {} busybox:latest env
# prints out
docker run -e a=b -e c=d busybox:latest env 
# which works if I copy paste?
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=854ec1dc608e
a=b
c=d
HOME=/root
```

Comment: `xargs` doesn't do word splitting after replacing `{}`. It's just one argument.

Comment: Have you considered using a higher-level language in combination with a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to do this?  Even the task of parsing the JSON and constructing the container environment will probably be more straightforward than trying to do it in a shell pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce that `-t` behavior with Linux's `xargs`, anyway below CLI should deterministically work, assuming that the `K=V` env array is "clean" enough (i.e. without special characters).

Details:

- use `jq` to build a newline- separated k=v list
- use `sed` to prefix it with `-e`
- use `xargs bash -c '.... ${@} ...' --` construct, to let bash "expand" the whole passed array of arguments

```shell
echo '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}' |\
  jq -r '. | to_entries | map([.key,.value] | join("=")) | join("\n")' |\
  sed 's/^/-e /' |\
  xargs bash -c 'docker run "${@}" busybox:latest env' --
```

Comment: `$@` should **always** be in double quotes; otherwise it acts just like unquoted `$*`, with all the bugs that implies.

Comment: Also, think about using the `-d $'\n'` argument to `xargs` so it's expecting output to be line-oriented rather than word-oriented. If you don't use `-0` or `-d`, xargs treats `two words` as two separate items, and `line with "some quoted words"` as three items, `line`, `with`, and `some quoted words`.

Comment: Good point, thanks @CharlesDuffy, fixed.

Comment: Maybe you could get rid of the `sed` with `echo '{"a": "b", "c": "d"}' |  jq -r '. | to_entries | map([.key,.value] | join("=") | ("-e", .)) | join("\n")' | xargs -d $'\n' ...`. There's a bug there if the number of items causes xargs to run docker more than once, but I think things were a bit dodgy under those circumstances already.